# The plain text alternative of notification emails is not usable

Tags: feature-request

As I imagine that happens for every other Stack* user, I receive eventual emails about questions I have made/comment and changes in my account here.

I usually don't see the HTML version of these messages because its colors are totally different from the colors I prefer to use, and the colors I have in the mail clients I use, web or not. There is a text version of the message, as it happens for most emails. But Stack* messsages have a very bad version. I'll show 3 things here the full text version of a message; a meta-description manually made of what I can see in the HTML version; and a suggestion of what could have been automatically made for the text version of the message (using old, simple but very good ideas that had worked for a few decades around the world).

1. Text version of the message. Note the amount of spaces used in it. Also note that I have not added or changed any newline characters. The full message is what I paste here:

```
                                comment


                                Sep 14 at 22:39




                        Is there a full XMPP client, for any mobile? [that sends/receives files, etc., like PC clients do]


                        You may want to check the "xmpp" tag on Software Recommendations (and/or ask your quest...











                                answer


                                Sep 10 at 14:10




                        Need a captcha for JavaScript less page


                        JavaScript is required to view Stack Exchange. This will be status-declined.












                                answer


                                Sep 10 at 14:02




                        Need a captcha for JavaScript less page


                        Your question sounds more of a rant than a question. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with t...











                                comment


                                Sep 10 at 12:25




                        Need a captcha for JavaScript less page


                        For the record, I've had the JS reCAPTCHA prompt appear when submitting a question, and my te...







                    Want instant inbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS or Android!




















_________________________________________________________________________

    Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](hXXP//meta.stackexchange.com).
            If you no longer wish to receive updates weekly, you may [unsubscribe from this email](hTTP//meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/6321188/76fdd32b1fdb99e2a4d487dfe63824f173d036fe7fd106129736d8191a7825fe).


Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038
```

2. The message, as we can see in the HTML version, in pseudo XML here, and comments starting with "#":

   ```
   <stack exchange logo> # or other logos, varying in other messages

   <dark blue background box>The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2015-09-10:
   </dark blue background box>


   <image "apple touch icon" />
   comment     Sep 14 at 22:39 
   <link href='hTTP//unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/391920?noredirect=1'>Is there a full XMPP client, for any mobile? [that sends/receives files, etc., like PC clients do]
   </link>

   You may want to check the "xmpp" tag on Software Recommendations (and/or ask your quest...


   answer  Sep 10 at 14:10 
   <link href=''>
   Need a captcha for JavaScript less page 
   </link>
    JavaScript is required to view Stack Exchange. This will be status-declined. 
           answer  Sep 10 at 14:02 

   <link href=''>
   Need a captcha for JavaScript less page 
   </link>
    Your question sounds more of a rant than a question. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with t... 
           comment     Sep 10 at 12:25 

   <link href=''>
   Need a captcha for JavaScript less page 
   </link>

   For the record, I've had the JS reCAPTCHA prompt appear when submitting a question, and my te... 


   Want instant inbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS or Android!

   <imagelink href='hTTP//stackoverflow.com/redirect?t=1&s=1&u=6321188'>
       iOS app on the App Store
   </imagelink>
   <imagelink href='hTTP//stackoverflow.com/redirect?t=2&s=1&u=6321188'>
       Android app on Google Play
   </imagelink>


   <bottom text, very clear font in white background; awful to read!>

   Questions? Comments? Let us know on our <link href='hTTP//meta.stackexchange.com/'>feedback site</link>. If you no longer wish to receive updates weekly, you may <link href='hTTP//meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/6321188/76fdd32b1fdb99e2a4d487dfe63824f173d036fe7fd106129736d8191a7825fe'>unsubscribe from this email</link>. 

   Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038 <some form of text, with a title that we may see or not even note its existence; title='because we care'; color='maroon'>3</some>

   </bottom text, very clear font in white background; awful to read!>
   ```
3. As we have noted, the signature is the only really useful part in the text message. But it could be a good simple, complete and concise text message. For example:

```
The following 4 items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2015-09-10:

- a comment, date Sep 14 at 22:39, in the question:
    Is there a full XMPP client, for any mobile? [that sends/receives files, etc., like PC clients do]
    hTTP//unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/391920

    "You may want to check the ''xmpp'' tag on Software Recommendations (and/or ask your quest [...]"

- an answer, date Sep 10 at 14:10, in the question:
    Need a captcha for JavaScript less page
    hXXp//...com/123456/#654321

    "JavaScript is required to view Stack Exchange. This will be status-declined."

- a comment, date Sep 10 at 12:25, in the question:
    Need a captcha for JavaScript less page 
    hXXp//...com/123456/#654321

For the record, I've had the JS reCAPTCHA prompt appear when submitting a question, and my te... 

- an answer, date Sep 10 at 14:02 , in the question:
    Need a captcha for JavaScript less page 
    hXXp//...com/123456/#654321

    "Your question sounds more of a rant than a question. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with t... "



==================================
Want instant inbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS or Android!

hXXp//stack...com/mobileapps/


==================================
Questions? Comments? Let us know on our Feedback site:
    hXXp//meta.stackexchange.com

If you no longer wish to receive updates weekly, you may unsubcribe from this email:
    hXXp//meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/6321188/76fdd32b1fdb99e2a4d487dfe63824f173d036fe7fd106129736d8191a7825fe

Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038 3

"Because we care"
```

Notes on the above example, that I have built using some assumed "restrictions" from the actual message:

- the comments made on questions, even the short ones are cut out to be short, even in the middle of the words. May be needless, since the comment are restricted to one line (the newlines in the are filtered out, if present); and so are usually short, could be fully included in the message.
- the used dates could have a chosen format that the user prefers. Wikipedia, for example, let we choose the ISO format, a local format, or any other we may feel pleased and are used to read, instead of the English format that are somewhat harder to read for people around the world, where English is not their natural language.
- Since it is only one URL for both mobile apps, as we saw up there, it can be a readable one like the given example. Simple. Perfect. :)
- The unsubscribe URL could be smaller, couldn't it?